# Access WinForm in OnFocusChanged()

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have created a list "exe" and new WinForm in Main(). I need to access both in OnFocusChanged(). The idea is that a hidden WinForm is created, and when "firefox" has focus, the WinForm will be displayed. My WinForm has a method, update(), that is used to show the WinForm. If I call "form.update()" in Main, the WinForm appears, however I cannot access it in OnFocusChanged().

How can I access the list and WinForm object in OnFocusChanged()? Thanks.

```
namespace WinForm1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            List<string> exe = new List<string>();

            Form1 form = new Form1();
            Application.Run(form);
        }
        static private void OnFocusChanged(object sender, AutomationFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string program = "firefox";
            if(exe.Any(program.Contains)
            {
                form.update(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I subscribe to it? I have placed all of this code in Program.cs.

Answer (score 1):

`exe` can't be accessed from the OnFocusChanged event handler because it's local in scope to the Main method.

You need to make the list variable `static` and bring it outside of the method

```
...
static List<string> exe = new List<string>();

[STAThread]
static void Main()
...
```

Comment: You could do the same thing (making the `form` variable static). If the form itself is raising the OnFocusChanged event, you could access it from the `sender` parameter.

Comment: Am I doing this the right way? I need to detect when a focus event occurs and then change the text of my WinForm accordingly. Could you provide a sample of how I might code it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use System.Diagnostics.Process for archive to this idea

first get list of all process and check process name

```
        Process[] processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();

        if (processes.Any(c => c.ProcessName == "firefox"))
        {
           //your update code
        }
```